# d3fc - Candlestick multi-series Cartesian chart

Tags: d3fc

How can I render a multi-series, cartesian chart with candlesticks?

I have this currently:

http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/af3258802b35d6dc327dc813eb4c32e0"

On line 63:

```
d3.select(nodes[i])
  .select('svg')
  .call(candlestickSeries);
```

The above works, but the following doesn't:

```
 const multiSeries = fc.seriesSvgMulti()
     .series([
        candlestickSeries,
        volumeSeries
     ])

 const cartesianChart = fc.chartSvgCartesian(
        xScale,
        yScale
     )
     .plotArea(multiSeries);

 ...

 d3.select(nodes[i])
  .select('svg')
  .call(multiSeries); //or  .call(cartesianChart)
```

I need to render a candle chart + volume multi-series with gridlines. I can't find any examples of these things combined.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to determine what is wrong with your code, however, you might find the following example, which combines an OHLC series with volume, to be useful:

https://bl.ocks.org/ColinEberhardt/485ad09b7967e2a0f9bfe6e10192c26a

[image]